# Hadoop Administration: Admin Command to merge fsimage and edits log

Tags: hadoop, command, admin

Is it correct to use `HADOOP_HOME/hadoop dfsadmin -saveNamespace` to merge the fsimage and edits in Hadoop cluster without restring the namenode?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the command usage to save the Namespace is

```
hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace
```

This command would save the namespace image (from memory) directly to disk which is faster than rolling and merging of edits with the fsimage stored in disk.

Before saving Namespace, make sure the `safemode` is turned ON.

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter
```

Namenode restart is not required to save namespace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter` and this `hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace` will merge the fsimage and edits without using Secondary Namenode right?

Comment: Yes, this does not involve SecondaryNamenode.

Comment: Thank You. Your answer is helpful for me. One more doubt. After this command, the output will be a new `fsimage` under `HADOOP_HOME/hadoop/data/Namenode/current`, right?

Comment: Thank You for the support @franklinsijo